# What is the pythonic way to replace `nan` when extracting a single value from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, fillna

I have a dataframe containing `NaN` values as well as floats

```
In: import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,np.nan],[np.nan,4]],columns=['col1','col2'],index=    ['row1','row2'])
    df
Out:
    col1    col2
row1    1.0     NaN
row2    NaN     4.0
```

To extract a row, or column and fill `NaN` values, I can use `.fillna()`

```
In: df.loc[:,'col1'].fillna(99.0)
Out: 
    row1     1.0
    row2    99.0
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

But `.fillna()` will not work on a single value. So I have this:

```
In:
    if np.isnan(df.loc['row2','col1']):
       val = 99.0
    else:
        val = df.loc['row2','col1']
    val

Out:    99.0
```

This works, but is *very* clumsy compared to `.fillna()`. 
What is the pythonic way?

Comment: You can do it in one line: is `99.0 if np.isnan(df.loc['row2','col1']) else df.loc['row2','col1']` less clumsy in your opinion?

Comment: A *bit* less clumsy, but I would hope for something neater.

Comment: Why can't you call `fillna()` before accessing the value (as you showed in your first example)?

Comment: Can you talk more about your goal and why you want to fillna for specific values? The nice thing about fillna is that it takes care of filling missing values across your dataset as a whole

Comment: @Brayden I am setting `Class` variables based on a `dataframe` (read  from a `.csv` file) which is a table of parameters, all of which have different default values.

Comment: @pault I guess I can:
`val = df.fillna(99.0).loc['row2','col1']`
That looks better to me, but perhaps slow for a big `df` because all `NaN`s are filled instead of just the one I need?

Answer (score 0):

```
 df.fillna({'col1':99}, limit=1)

      col1  col2
row1   1.0   NaN
row2  99.0   4.0
```